# How to compose futures when the container item is an Either

Tags: scala, playframework

My code below was working fine when my return values where `Either[String, User]` and `Either[String, Seq[Sale]]`.

My functions actually return Futures, so once I wrapped them in futures I am facing issues.

I need help on how to compose Futures when the inner container is of Either type.

Note: I will have to perform further business logic on the sales collection but the general outline of what I need have so far is below:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


case class User(id: Int)
case class Sale(id: Int)

case class Response(user: User, sales: Seq[Sale])

def getUser(id: Int): Future[Either[String, User]] = Future(Right(User(123)))
def getSales(userId: Int): Future[Either[String, Seq[Sale]]] = Future(Right(Seq(Sale(1), Sale(2))))

val response = for {
  user <- getUser(123)
  sales <- getSales(user.id)
} yield Response(user, sales)

println(response)
```

I am doing this inside of a playframework action method:

```
def getUser(id: Int) = Action.async {

   val response = for {
      user <- getUser(123)
      sales <- getSales(user.id)
    } yield Response(user, sales)

  Ok(response) // gets converted to JSON
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't facing issues mean? Doesn't compile? Doesn't run? Unexpected results? Please add details to your question.

Comment: here is my scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KoNbnFi4QDiUsKXQjLgF7g

Comment: You have three options: 1) use `EitherT` _(either from **cats** or reimplement it yourself)_ - 2) Manually compose the inner `flatMaps` every time. - 3) Remove the `Either` and work with the error channel of `Future` _(but you would need to use `Exceptios` instead of `Strings`)_

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for #2, do you mean have a for-comp with a nested for-comp inside of it?

Comment: Mostly yes, but you will find `for` to just add noise and not help at all, so you will probably return to just plain literal `flatMaps`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if you can answer with details for #2 that would be great.  I updated my question with the playframework Action method that I am working on to give more context...

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [`cats.data.EitherT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html). It exists exactly for that purpose:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._

val response = for {
  user <- EitherT(getUser(123))
  sales <- EitherT(getSales(user.id))
} yield Response(user, sales)

response.value.onComplete(println)
```

Comment: sorry I can't introduce that library to this project.

Comment: @Blankman Then you have to do exactly what `EitherT` does yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot use cats, then you have to implement the transformer yourself. Here is an example for an `Either[String,_]`: ([Link to Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TIuN06knTlC3UxeQ4vUAAA))

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   
case class FutureEither[A](value: Future[Either[String,A]]){
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): FutureEither[B] = FutureEither(value.map(_.map(f)))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => FutureEither[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): FutureEither[B] = FutureEither(value.flatMap{
    case Left(s) => Future.successful(Left(s))
    case Right(a) => f(a).value
  })
}

case class User(id: Int)
case class Sale(id: Int)    
case class Response(user: User, sales: Seq[Sale])

def getUser(id: Int): Future[Either[String, User]] = Future(Right(User(123)))
def getSales(userId: Int): Future[Either[String, Seq[Sale]]] = Future(Right(Seq(Sale(1), Sale(2))))

val response = for {
  user <- FutureEither(getUser(123))
  sales <- FutureEither(getSales(user.id))
} yield Response(user, sales)

println(response.value.onComplete(println(_)))
```

Note that you can easily abstract over the wrapping `Future[_]`. It only has to be a monad (needs to have `map` and `flatMap` and `apply` method). If you do this, and add some more syntactic niceties, you'll end up with `EitherT` from cats.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is very painful and it would be better to use any of the other alternatives.

```scala
getUser(123).flatMap {
  case Right(user) =>
    getSales(user.id).map {
      case Right(sales) =>
        Right(Response(user, sales))

      case left =>
        left
    }

  case left =>
    Future.succesful(left)
}
```